# How to validate customer account fields in magento

Tags: magento, customer-account-data-api

I have created a field with Type 1 and Type 2 in the user registration page. If the user selected the Type 1 all the fields should be validated it works for me. When the user selected the Type 2 at that time need to validate which fields want to validate..How will do this...Please help

Comment: Two types of users Type 1 and Type2. For one users all fields to be validate and the other user some form fields to be validate.

Comment: you can achieve this using jquery . if type1 is selected then all fields would be required and if type2 is selected than remove class requred-entry from those fields

Comment: Ya I have tried by using the jquery but when we using the "required entry" it will remove the border from the input box but the custom validation message still appear..

Comment: remove validate-password validate-email this kind of class as well

Comment: still getting same Error??

Comment: Thanks for your help...By using the display none attribute i have fixed the issue...